# How should I attach this insulation to a broken window pane?

Tags: insulation

I got some insulation to patch this broken window pane in my basement. Any suggestions for attaching it? Should I do the whole window or just the relevant pane? I was thinking of just using a strong tape and taping it right on but wondering if that’s a bad idea or if there are other steps I need to take here.

[image]

Comment: Can someone get to the outside of that window?  Tape should go on a clean glass to hold better.

Comment: The best thing to do is fix the window.

Comment: What @RMDman said... it should be possible to remove the entire sash from the hinges at the top corners... then new glass is either a diy or 'take it to a glass repair place' kind of thing. There are probably answers here about replacing old glass; if there aren't, feel free to ask.